# i am try to download multi file from a URL in R download.file() files are download but all are not opeing

Tags: r, web-scraping

download.file(mainurl,filename,method="curl") method try with “wget”, “curl”, "auto"

```
url <- "https://exporter.nih.gov/ExPORTER_Catalog.aspx"
linksu <- getURL(url)
links <- getHTMLLinks(linksu)
filenames <- links[str_detect(links, ".zip")]

filenames_list <- as.list(filenames)

downloadzip <- function (mainurl,filename) {
  filedetails <- str_c(mainurl,filename)
  print(filename)
  require(downloader)
  download.file(mainurl,filename,method="curl")
}

# save the files into the current Dir.
l_ply(filenames,downloadzip,mainurl = "https://exporter.nih.gov/")

#downloaded csv file this is works
download.file("https://exporter.nih.gov/CSVs/final/RePORTER_PRJ_C_FY2019_053.zip",destfile ="test.zip" )
```

download success full all files but all are corrupted

Comment: does the `download.file` in the final line of code work (it does for me)? If not, can you add your session details please/

Comment: yes last line works for me. but when try to download multiple files then files was downloading successfully but all are corrupted.

Comment: I suspect it is how you are creating the links. If you only use the links that start http, without the appending it does seem to download correct files: `filenames <- links[str_detect(links, "^http.*\\.zip$")] ; mapply(download.file, filenames, destfile=basename(filenames))`. So id check that the files paths that you are concatenating exist.

Comment: ps please do add the packages you are using to complete your example

Comment: i am use R packages # install.packages("RCurl")
# install.packages("httr")
# install.packages("XML")
# install.packages("stringr")
#install.packages("plyr")
#install.packages("downloader")

Comment: now i am Getting proper files

i change here 

downloadzip <- function (mainurl,filename) {
  filedetails <- str_c(mainurl,filename)
  print(filedetails)
  require(downloader)
  download.file(filedetails,filename,method="curl")
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
downloadzip <- function (mainurl,filename) {
  filedetails <- str_c(mainurl,filename)
  print(filedetails)
  require(downloader)
  download.file(filedetails,filename,method="curl")
}
```

** this working for me **